# Javascript function to read object's property (instrumenting read object's property)

Tags: javascript

**The question:**
How can a I implement a function in JavaScript which would behave exactly the same as read property,
but will log the values

I.e.

```
function f(obj, prop) {
    console.log(obj, prop, obj[prop]);
    return obj[prop];
}
```

But with respect to preserving this value and other pitfalls.

**Question context:** I'm developing some instrumetation tool for Javascript.
I'm using Babel to parse the code, than I manipulate AST tree to replace reads from object properties.

For source code

```
a.b[5].c(1,2,3);
```

I produce instrumented code like this one:

```
const LOG_READ = (z)=> {console.log('LOGGED', z); return z;}
LOG_READ(
    LOG_READ(
        LOG_READ(
            a
            , "b")
        , 5)
        , "c")(1,2,3);
```

I had a problem with:

```
let x = [1,2,3];
x.map(it => console.log(it));
```

Instrumented to:

```
let x = [1,2,3];
LOG_READ(x, "map")(it => console.log(it));
```

It failed to run when instrumented, because "map" expects "this" to be equal to "x" which isn't.
When I fixed LOG_READ to

```
const LOG_READ = (obj, prop)=> {console.log('LOGGED', z); return (typeof z === "function" ? obj[prop].bind(obj) : z}
```

It failed for

```
class c1 extends LOG_READ(module, "func_name") {...}
```

Because bind should not be called for this case, so it became:

```
const LOG_READ = (obj, prop)=> {console.log('LOGGED', obj, prop); return (typeof obj[prop] === "function" && !obj[prop].prototype ? obj[prop].bind(obj) : obj[prop]}
```

As you might guess it failed again in some else place.
I've also tried making a proxy or an expression instead of function - they also don't work.
I.e. (LOG_WRITE_PROXY.w = a.map)(it => console.log(it));
So here is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do here, but did you know that Array.prototype.map accepts a second argument to set the value of *this* ? cf. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map

Comment: Also, as a different point, if you're transforming `x.map` to `LOG_READ(x.map)` and you apply the same transformation to *any* method, then you will be losing the `this` context all the time. Unless it's already bound. So, why not bind it yourself and generate `LOG_READ(x.map.bind(x))`. I don't think logging the values on read will really help you solve the fundamental problem of transforming the code and loosing the original semantics. EDIT: I now notice that you say "bind should not be called" which is odd but you can do `LOG_READ(x.map, x)` and then inside `LOG_READ(fn, ctx) {fn.call(ctx)}`

Comment: @giuseppedeponte I know that, but this won't help because i need a universal solution, not just for "map" function

Comment: @VLAZ No I can't. LOG_READ should return function which is than called, it can't call by itself because it don't have args to call the function. In your example there is no place for map's callback.

Comment: Yes, `x.map.bind(x)` returns a function

Comment: Why not use a proxy for this?

Comment: @YuriYaryshev it was an illustrative example because I ran out of characters for the comment. Point is, that if you can't use `.bind`, then you can still re-create it via `.call`. Just return a new function that will make sure the function is called with the correct context - the same thing `.bind` does. And since you are in charge of what code gets generated, you should be able to make it work.

Comment: @trincot I tried Proxy, but also got stuck with too many other edge cases with it. As an example: class a extends new Proxy(b, handler).c {} would hit error where "get" expects prototype to be returned, but I return Proxy(prototype) which doesn't shout some proxy's "trap" for get. Anyway that approach is a good other topic to discuss...

Comment: Well, I still went ahead and posted an answer based on Proxy.

Comment: @trincot Thanks. I'm trying this out. But this approach really seems problematic. Another example: this.a = LOG_READ(x, "y"); - in case if x.y is an object, would store a Proxy to this.a which whould result is real pain later - because that Proxy would go all over the app...

Comment: I also wonder why you consider that the `extends` clause needs a `log_read`, since at runtime this is not an executable statement, so no *read* is happening there.

Comment: @trincot I'm not, it's just an example, in fact I excluded it. I have others, but harder to explain them out of context.

Comment: If you excluded it, then maybe exclude it also from your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200776/discussion-between-yuri-yaryshev-and-trincot).

Comment: @VLAZ .bind and .call have common problem: I can't decide when I should or should not .bind (.call), - the problem is figuring out correct condition...

Comment: @VLAZ your solution was the closest. What solved all my problems: first instrument all calls to LOG_CALL(obj, prop, ...args) => obj[prop](...args), and only after that done - instrument reads with LOG_READ(obj,prop) => obj[prop]. This requires no Proxy, no bind or call, no magic-dancing - it just works fine now. If you wish to post an answer - please do so I could accept it. Or I can answer it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Someone linked [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) in a comment, however a bit later the comment disappeared. I thought there would an answer come, but apparently it has not.
However `Proxy` seems to be related and interesting, see this test:

```js
var something={
  a:1,
  b:[2,3,4],
  c:{
    d:"Hello",
    e:[5,6,7]
  }
};

var handler = {
    get: function(obj, prop) {
      console.log(prop.toString()+" requested: "+obj[prop]);
      if(prop in obj){
        var p=obj[prop];
        if(p instanceof Object || p instanceof Array)
          return new Proxy(p,handler);
        return p;
      }
      return undefined;
    }
};

var proxd=new Proxy(something,handler);

console.log(proxd.a+proxd.b.reduce((a,i)=>a+i)+proxd.c.e[2]);
```

So it does something with this simple throwaway recursion already, like cutting through the `this` issue appearing in the comments (`reduce` just works fine).